# Did the ship visit Hell in the biblical sense, or more like a Deadite universe?

Tags: event-horizon

In the *[Event Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Horizon_%28film%29)* movie, the crew figures out the ship has been to "Hell".

But I'm curious; does it go to Hell in a biblical sense, or does it visit something more akin to the universe the [Cenobites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cenobite_%28Hellraiser%29) (*from [Hellraiser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellraiser_%28franchise%29)*) come from?

Comment: I know this is not constructive, but that was a very stupid movie.

Comment: Personally I really like the theory (even if it's not official) that the ship visited essentially the same ["warp"](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Immaterium) as in the `Warhammer 40,000` universe, Chaos and all.

Comment: @eidylon I thought exactly that the first time I've seen the movie

Comment: Deadites are from Evil Dead; I think you mean the [Cenobites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cenobite_%28Hellraiser%29).  Editing to reflect this; please roll back if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The ship travels by using a black hole to create a wormhole, but instead of Proxima Centauri, the wormhole led to an alternate dimension, "a dimension of pure chaos, pure evil." So I suppose whether that qualifies as the hell from the bible depends on your interpretation. I don't recall any of the flashbacks including the torment of long-dead souls, so I'd suggest that no, it's not the biblical hell, just a terrible place.

Comment: Agreed, all of the scenes that show torture are of the crew, and seems to have them die (which would seem to disprove a biblical Hell).

Answer (score 8):

Well there was a scene that didn't make it in, and in that scene Millers not actually fighting Weir he's fighting the entity that came back with the ship.  Miller asks it if it is the devil and the entity tells him he's not the devil but "the darkness behind the stars" and that "it had been around since before the Big Bang" so no it's not hell

Comment: Was this shot or is it just from the script?

Answer (score 6):

No, but where ever the place is that the ship visits, it looks an awful lot like the things HP Lovecraft dreamt up. Also, Deadites are from the Raimi movies, it was Cenobites in the Hellbound Heart.

Comment: Looking at the "hell" scenes [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuJnIJHgQ44), they look like Hellraiser-style body horror to me, nothing particularly Lovecraftian about them (no alien biologies or cyclopean monuments or non-euclidean geometries to be seen)

Comment: @Hypnosifl The premise of the movie is "non-euclidian geometry leads to horror". Have you not seen it?

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. There aren't any visible instances of geometry appearing "wrong" to the characters as in some Lovecraft stories like Call of Cthulhu, and there is nothing about the hell dimension that "looks an awful lot like the things HP Lovecraft dreamt up" in any visible sense, non-euclidean geometry is only involved in the plot point that the gateway to hell was opened by a black hole that created a shortcut in space like a wormhole, and black holes/wormholes are theoretical solutions to Einstein's theory of general relativity, which deals with gravity using non-euclidean geometry.

Answer (score 2):

Although the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Event-Horizon.html) is relatively vague, there's enough contextual clues to make a reasonable assumption that the ship was **actually in hell**.

- The distress call literally translates as

> "***Save yourself. From Hell***"

- Justin states that he's been in

> "***The other place***"

- The script refers to Miller being shown...

> "**VISIONS FROM HELL**"

Comment: These are all things people would say about any particularly horrific place. People say similar things about warzones, for instance. I think it's expressive language not meant to imply the literally went to the afterlife Hell.

Comment: @CreationEdge - You're not wrong. But in the absence of a source suggesting otherwise, why should we not take them at face value?

Comment: Because descriptive language such as this is rarely taken at face value? And, considering the whole rest of the movie is dealing with Sci-Fi and space horror, not supernatural horror, bringing a supernatural element into it doesn't really jive. If there were a hint at anything else religious or supernatural in the film, then maybe this interpretation would make sense.

Comment: @CreationEdge - If you take a gander at the novelisation, it's literally packed to the gunwales with biblical references.

Comment: So was BSG:ToS. It's not uncommon in literature, even sci-fi, to include copious amounts of biblical or mythological references.

Comment: A novel doesn't literally have gunwales, and besides, why couldn't the novelisation have gone the other way?

Comment: @Beta - No reason, except that they didn't write it like that.

Comment: @Beta - It may also interest you to know that [literally](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/literally) doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 2):

The original captain of the *Event Horizon*, after gouging his own eyes out, speaks a warning in Latin.  Perhaps, then, the most relevant question is whether he or any member of the original crew knew Latin before they turned the experimental hyperdrive on.

It stands to reason that if no one on the crew ever learned this language before the incident, it must have been taught to the captain by someone or something other than a crewmember after the activation of the drive.  Since literal Biblical demons are frequently depicted as speaking Latin in modern media, this would be evidence in favor of the *Event Horizon* having passed through the literal Biblical Hell, rather than merely some unpleasant alien dimension.

In short, who taught the captain Latin?  Was it a demon?

Comment: Lots of people know more Latin than they would imagine. Just think about how many TV shows you've watched in your life where they have latin chanting, background music, etc etc.